# Circuit with diodes (forward-inverse)

Tags: voltage, diodes, circuit-analysis

I'm trying to solve an exercise and I don't know if I'm doing things in the correct way. And I can't find the solution.

I have this circuit:

[image]

I put a voltmeter between + and - of D1 and see the drop voltage. Something like this:

[image]

This is what I'm doing:
First of all, I have the characteristic curve of a diode:

[image]

and I know that V_breakdown = 100V.

I see if I can say that \$V_{D1} = 0.7\$ V:

$$10\text{V} - I \times 1\text{k}\Omega - 0.7\text{V} = 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ I = 9.3\text{mA}$$

Now, I go to the definition of the current through the diode:

$$I_D = I_S \left(\text{exp}\left(\frac{V_D}{V_{th}} - 1\right)\right) = 14.5\text{mA} $$ 
(I considered \$V_{th} = 25\$mA and \$I_S = 10^{-14}\$)

\$I_D\$ is bigger than \$I\$, so I'm in **cut-off**

So, I go back and say:

$$I_{D1} = I_{D2} = I_S \left(\text{exp}\left(\frac{V_D}{V_{th}} - 1\right)\right)$$

and
$$I_{R1} = I_{D1} = I_{D2}$$

So, looking the circuit:

$$10\text{V} - I_R 1\text{k}\Omega - V_{D1} - V_{D2} = 0$$

and

$$V_{D1} = \ln\left(\frac{I_D}{I_S} +1\right) V_{th}$$

but, if \$I_{D1} = I_{D2}\$, \$V_{D1} = V_{D2}\$ and **that's wrong** because the drop voltage in \$D_1\$ will be smaller than in \$D_2\$!!

I don't know what I'm doing in a wrong way.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!!!

PS: I simulated the circuit but I need to understand **why** that happens.

Comment: Your first equation ignores the voltage drop across D2.

Comment: Haven't read through everything yet, but your very first equation doesn't apply to your circuit because it neglects the voltage drop across D2.

Comment: And why do you think it's wrong for the drop across D1 to be smaller than D2? The drop across D2 will be very close to 10 V. The drop across D1 will be a couple hundred mV or less.

Comment: And in your 3rd equation you ignore the fact the two diodes are in opposite orientation.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use these equations:

$$10 \mathrm{V}-I\left(1\mathrm{k\Omega}\right)-V_{D1}-V_{D2}=0$$

$$I=I_s\exp\left(\frac{V_{D1}}{V_{th}}-1\right)$$

$$I=-I_s\exp\left(\frac{-V_{D2}}{V_{th}}-1\right)$$

(Notice that \$V_{D2}\$ appears with negative sign in the 3rd equation because D2 is oriented so that it will be reverse biased)

You could work out the algebra on this one, but it would be quicker to just plug the circuit into your favorite SPICE-like simulator and run an operating point analysis.

<strike>I'd expect \$V_{D2}\$ to come out somewhere in the neighborhood of 9.5 to 9.9 V, \$V_{D1}\$ to be 100 to 500 mV, and the voltage dropped by the resistor to be negligible.</strike>

I simulated the thing in LTSpice with 1N4148 type diode model, and got 9.97 V across D2, 30 mV across D1, and negligible drop across the resistor, with about 2.5 nA flowing in the circuit.

Comment: I have to solve it manually and I can't find the solution. Look:
$$10 V - I 1k\Omega - V_{D1} - V_{D2} = 0$$
$$I = I_S \exp(\frac{V_{D1}}{V_{th}} - 1)$$
$$I = I_S \exp(\frac{-V_{D2}}{V_{th}} - 1)$$
So,

$$V_{D1} = ln(\frac{I}{I_S} +1) V_{th}$$
$$V_{D2} = - ln(\frac{I}{I_S} +1) V_{th}$$

I put that in the first equation and get:

$$10V - I 1k\Omega - ln(\frac{I}{I_S} + 1) V_{th} + ln(\frac{I}{I_S} +1) V_{th} = 0$$

So,

$$10V - I 1 \ k\Omega = 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ I = 10mA$$

:S

Comment: Sorry, see edit in 3rd equation.

Comment: But if I use that, I have:

$$I_{D1} = I_S (\exp(\frac{V_{D1}}{V_{th}}) - 1)$$
$$I_{D2} = - I_S (\exp(\frac{-V_{D2}}{V_{th}}) - 1)$$

So, like I_D1 = I_D2 and I_S = I_S:
$$\exp(\frac{V_{D1}}{V_{th}}) - 1 = - \exp(\frac{-V_{D2}}{V_{th}}) + 1$$
So, I get this:
$$\exp(\frac{V_{D1}}{V_{th}}) + \exp(\frac{-V_{D2}}{V_{th}})  = 2$$

How can I solve that??

Comment: You still have two unknowns. You could invert these equations and substitute back into the KVL equation. Then use Newton-Raphson iteration or other method of your choice. But it will be very tedious to solve by hand.

Comment: Practically, you can just say that \$I\approx{}I_s\$, \$V_{D2}\approx{}10 \mathrm{V}\$, \$V_{D1}\approx0 \mathrm{V}\$

Comment: Current is very low, 0. So Vd1 is 0, VR is 0, remaining Vd2 is equal to V1. No equations required.

Comment: if I put that in:

$$ \exp(\frac{V_{D1}}{V_{th}}) + \exp(\frac{-V_{D2}}{V_{th}})$$

I get:
$$ \exp(0) + \exp(\frac{-10}{25mV}) = 1 + \exp(-400) \approx 1$$

and I said that it was equal to 2!!!


I could fix that. With V_D1 = 0.005V I reach an approximate solution. Thanks everyone

Comment: Can I say that, in reverse bias (D2), I=I_S?

If I can say that, the equation is a bit simpler and I don't lose too much information

Comment: In the limit of very large reverse bias (but below the breakdown voltage), then the reverse current approaches \$I_s\$. You can draw the graph yourself to see how much reverse bias is needed to get how close to \$I_s\$.

Answer (score 0):

The engineering way to solve this isn't to dive into exponential equations but approximate the current through the circuit as the reverse (leakage) current through the reverse-biased diode D2; that's because our intuition tells us it will be the element that will "oppose the most" the flow of current (give that the resistor is only 1k). The diode, being an 1N4001, is well-below its [breakdown voltage of 50V](http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/ds28002.pdf); 100V, which you assumed, is actually for 1N4002 by the way, but that issue makes no difference here.

Note that this reverse leakage current is highly dependent on temperature: for 1N400x is 5uA at 25C but ten times that (50uA) at 100C ambient. Besides that, these leakage currents are given in the datasheet at max reverse voltage. They'll probably be less at only 10V, but there's no graph for that in the datasheet, so... you should probably interpolate linearly.

Also note that "The Photon" used a different diode, which has much lower leakage current [of 25nA](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/1N4148_1N4448.pdf) at 25C ambient, but goes to 50uA as well at 150C. For that diode we actually get a graph of reverse current (fig 5), but only two curves are plotted at 75V and 20V (reverse voltage.)

Comment: Thanks! I know that, but I needed to reach the solution trying to make no approximations (I know that, for example, I took I_S = 10^-14 and it can be 10^-15)

Comment: @Juan. Then use a computer because these non-linear equations cannot be easily solved by hand, especially as a system. Also, in your question you said "I need to understand why that happens" not that you need a precise analytical solution.

Comment: And I also need to understand what's happening. For example, why I=-I_S (...) in the reverse diode?